# PowerShell console host displays strings inconsistently

Tags: powershell

When I run this in PowerShell ISE, both strings are displayed identically.
When I run it in the console host, string $a is missing the empty line.
Why is that, and can I work around it?
I want to format blocks of text without using `n

```
$a = "there should be one emtpy line

between these two lines of text"

$b = "there should be one emtpy line`n`nbetween these two lines of text"

$a
$b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type that into the console host, you're correct; it won't work as expected. But if you save it in a file, then it does work as expected (the blank line is preserved).

I believe that this is because of the way the console host is using blank lines to interpret your input, since it needs to detect blank lines to tell when to stop input in some cases.

I don't know enough to know if it's a bug.

Something else that may not be clear is that when you write the way you're assigning it to `$a`, you're actually inserting CR and LF ("`r`n") when in the ISE host, whereas with $b you're just using LF. In the console host, a LF only is used.

To see that, I like to use `[RegEx]::Escape`:

```
[RegEx]::Escape($a)
[RegEx]::Escape($b)
```

Using this I was able to confirm that using the console host to enter the strings, the second LF is actually not present in the `$a` string; it's not simply a display issue.